# Self and Earl Bird numbers: are there infinitely many natural numbers that are both?

Tags: mathematics, sequence

Self-numbers ([A003052](https://oeis.org/A003052) in the OEIS) are natural numbers which are not the sum of a smaller number and the sum of its digits. Early Bird numbers ([A116700](https://oeis.org/A116700)) are numbers that occur ahead of their natural place in the string 12345678910111213....

Are there infinitely many numbers, such as 110, that are both a Self-number (because no number smaller than 110 exists such that added to the sum of its digits equals 110) and an Early Bird number (because in the string 12345...9910010**110**2103... **110** appears earlier than its natural place, just a few digits further)?

Comment: The following are the first few numbers belonging to both sequences: 31, 42, 53, 64, 75, 86, 97, 110, 121, 132, 211, 222, 233, 310, 312, 323, 334, 345, 411, 413, 424, 435, 501, 512, 514, 525, 536, 547, 591, 602, 613, 615, 626, 637, 648, 659, 681, 692, 703, 714, 716, 727, 738, 749, 760, 771, 782, 793, 804, 815, 817, 828, 839, 850, 861, 872, 883, 894, 905, 916, 918, 929, 940, 951, 962, 973, 984, 995, 1021, 1109, 1111, 1122, ..., 2022, ...

Comment: And not until 2110 will the year in course be both an Early Bird number and a Self-number!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are:

Proof: Given a number which is both, we'll construct a larger number that is also both.

Assuming we have such a number n we'll in addition assume that n+10 has k digits and that 10 + k x 9 < n which is e.g. satisfied by OP's example n = 110 and for any larger number. We'll also assume that n starts with a 1, a property that will trivially be preserved by the construction below.

Let J be the smallest positive number such that the last digit of n+J is 1. We claim that N := n+J + 10^k + 10^(k+1) + ... + 10^(k+J-1) is also both. Indeed, if N were non self, let M be the number that makes it so, i.e. N = M + digitsum(M). M must have the same number of digits as N with J leading digits 1. Removing the J leading 1s would yield a number m that renders n non self, a contradiction. As N starts and ends with a 1 (and its second digit is either 1 or 2) it is also early bird.

Answer (score 3):

> Yes, there are infinite such numbers. My proof is based on this reduction test that can found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_number).
>  [image]

> Take $a = 1$ and $c = 10$. Then, $m_1 = 10 - 1 = 9$ which is a self-number and $m_2 = 9b - 11$.
>  So let us pick any $b$ such that $9b-11$ is also a self-number.
>  Note the self-number generating recurrence relation (from wiki) $C_k = 8 \cdot 10^{k - 1} + C_{k - 1} + 8, C_1 = 9$.
>  This implies $C_k = (C_{k-1} - 2) \mod 9$, which means every value congruent to modulo $9$ repeats after every $9$ terms. Thus, there are infinite self-numbers that are congruent to $7 \mod 9\;$ so there will be infinite possible values for $b$ as well.

> There is a $10$ at both the beginning and the end of this number so this is also an Early Bird number.

> For example, take $b=12$ then $m_2 = 9 \cdot 12 - 11 = 97$ which is a self-number so $10^{12} + 10 = 1000000000010$ is also a self-number. This is also an Early bird number because it's a prefix of $10000000000, 10000000001$.

Comment: Maybe it's there and I just didn't see it, but why are there infinitely many selfs = 7 mod 9?

Comment: @loopywalt the recurrence relation from the same wiki which says $C_k = 8 \cdot 10^{k - 1} + C_{k - 1} + 8$ implies $C_k = (C_{k-1} - 2) \mod 9$ so all values congruent to modulo 9 repeat after every 9 terms.

Comment: That's not something your average reader will know, so why not add it to your answer?

Comment: @loopywalt you're right, added it to the answer.

Comment: Now your answer is the high tech one and mine is the home brew ;-)