# Self-numbers and repunits

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, number-theory

Self-numbers or Colombian numbers (A003052 in the OEIS) are natural numbers which are not the sum of a smaller number and the sum of its digits. Repunits (in base 10) are numbers consisting only of 1's.

- a) Are there infinitely many Self-numbers which are repunits?
- b) Are there infinitely many repunits which are not Self-numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are there infinitely many repunits which are not Self-numbers?

> Yes. Consider any number with 1 repeated R_n times followed by n zeroes.
>  $10, \; \underbrace{11111111111}_{11\;\text{times}}00, \;\underbrace{11\cdots11}_{111\;\text{times}}000, \; \cdots$

Are there infinitely many Self-numbers which are repunits?

> Yes. Referring to the following reduction test from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_number) wiki (similar approach as [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/118625/44386) answer of mine):
>  [image]

> We can work backwards and always get values for b so infinite such values exist.
>  Example - Start with 110. Add 1 and append a 1 at the beginning to get the next self number. There will be infinite repunits in the process.

Comment: The "underbrace" mathjax looks broken in my browser (Chrome on MacOS): https://i.imgur.com/gkF1YgJ.png

Comment: @Bass no idea what is causing that issue, i will replace the mathjax with an image equivalent if i cant find a fix.